# jquery append dynamic data in tr

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to print my dynamic data in table, i can get my data but `tr` part in `tbody` has issue

[image: one]

each one of this data should show in separate tr but they all print in 1 tr only.

**This is the code of my issue part**

```
var jqrajdate = '';
var jqrajtime = '';
var jqrajcity = '';
var jqrajdescription = '';
$.each(manifest, function(key3, value3) {
  jqrajdate += value3['manifest_date'];
  jqrajtime += value3['manifest_time'];
  jqrajcity += value3['city_name'];
  jqrajdescription += value3['manifest_description'];
});
  $('div#proccess').append(
    '<div class="mb-20"><h4>Riwayat pengiriman</h4></div>'+
    '<table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">'+
    '<thead>'+
      '<th class="text-center">Tanggal</th>'+
      '<th class="text-center">Jam</th>'+
      '<th class="text-center">Kota</th>'+
      '<th class="text-center">Keterangan</th>'+
    '</thead>'+

    '<tbody>'+
      '<tr>'+
        '<td class="text-center">'+jqrajdate+'</td>'+
        '<td class="text-center">'+jqrajtime+'</td>'+
        '<td class="text-center">'+jqrajcity+'</td>'+
        '<td class="text-center">'+jqrajdescription+'</td>'+
      '</tr>'+
    '</tbody>'+
  '</table>'
  );
```

**Can anyone help me with fixing my tr issues?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your `manifest` is an array of objects, containing the keys `manifest_date`, `manifest_time`, and etc. In this case, you are doing it incorrectly because you are **concatenating/collapsing all values into a single variable** and then printing a single `<tr>` element. What you need to do is to move all that logic into the the `$.each()` loop instead.

You don't actually have to use `.$each()`, using a normal `Array.prototype.forEach()` should work. What you need to do is:

1. Create the necessary markup, but leave the `<tbody>` element empty
2. Since you are using the same keys to access the data, you can pre-declare them in an array to be used later
3. Loop through all entries in `manifest`. For each data row, you:

   - Create a new `<tr>` element
   - Loop through the keys (see step 2), and for each key you access, you create a new `<td>` element and append it to the ` element
   - Once you're done, append the `<tr>` element to your table's `<tbody>` element

See sample code below:

```
// 1. Create the markup and empty table beforehand
$('div#process').append('<div class="mb-20"><h4>Riwayat pengiriman</h4></div>'+
  '<table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">'+
  '<thead>'+
    '<th class="text-center">Tanggal</th>'+
    '<th class="text-center">Jam</th>'+
    '<th class="text-center">Kota</th>'+
    '<th class="text-center">Keterangan</th>'+
  '</thead>'+
  '<tbody></tbody>'+
  '</table>');

// 2. Loop through all entries in your array
var keys = ['manifest_date', 'manifest_time', 'city_name', 'manifest_description'];
manifest.forEach(function(row) {
  var $row = $('<tr />');

  keys.forEach(function(key) {
    $row.append('<td>' + row[key] + '</td>');
  });

  $('#table tbody').append($row);
});
```

Proof-of-concept example:

```js
// Dummy data
var manifest = [{
  'manifest_date': 'date1',
  'manifest_time': 'time1',
  'city_name': 'city1',
  'manifest_description': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 1'
}, {
  'manifest_date': 'date2',
  'manifest_time': 'time2',
  'city_name': 'city2',
  'manifest_description': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2'
}, {
  'manifest_date': 'date3',
  'manifest_time': 'time3',
  'city_name': 'city3',
  'manifest_description': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 3'
}];

// 1. Create the markup and empty table beforehand
$('div#process').append('<div class="mb-20"><h4>Riwayat pengiriman</h4></div>' +
  '<table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">' +
  '<thead>' +
  '<th class="text-center">Tanggal</th>' +
  '<th class="text-center">Jam</th>' +
  '<th class="text-center">Kota</th>' +
  '<th class="text-center">Keterangan</th>' +
  '</thead>' +
  '<tbody></tbody>' +
  '</table>');

// 2. Loop through all entries in your array
var keys = ['manifest_date', 'manifest_time', 'city_name', 'manifest_description'];
manifest.forEach(function(row) {
  var $row = $('<tr />');

  keys.forEach(function(key) {
    $row.append('<td>' + row[key] + '</td>');
  });

  $('#table tbody').append($row);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="process"></div>
```

Comment: it says `TypeError: keys.forEeach is not a function`

Comment: same error `TypeError: keys.forEeach is not a function`

Comment: @mafortis See the proof-of-concept code snippet I've added, it works as intended. If you are missing other elements, check your stylesheet or other possible influencing factors on your page. That's beyond my control and prediction of course.

Comment: can we get `$('#table tbody').append($row);` with anything else rather than #table? maybe my other table in page makes issue. i tried to use another id and class but it caused my table not to append.

Comment: @mafortis Then just swap it out for another ID, easy.

Comment: as i said when i did that it stop showing data, table won't load totally not header nor body part

Comment: @mafortis Did you change the `id="table"` in the script, too? Anyway, what you're asking is already beyond the scope of your original question: the proof-of-concept does work, so there's that.

Comment: yes i did, thanks for the help, you seems too angry! :)

Comment: @mafortis See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire ;)

Comment: found the issue :) it was you changed my div id `proccess` :))) Thanks man,